# SVN will not update a file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have used SVN quite a bit but today it is giving me a problem. I have a file which will not update. If I do a 'diff with previous version' it shows me the changes should be made. If I do an SVN update on the file it says it has done it but the file does not change.  I have done a 'clean'. I have deleted the whole repository and when the 'update' is done the latest version is still not fetched. It is almost as if when it does an update it does not fetch the latest version.

Confused now.

Comment: I deleted the whole tree and did a checkout -- same result!  It is determined to give me that file

Comment: How do you know that it doe not fetch the latest version? Have you checked your current revision (Properties of the file, tab Subversion) and the revision in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Update` menu item is meant to bring repository changes into your working copy. Since no changes are fetched, I'd say your file is up-to-date.

The `Diff with previous version` menu item shows the last changes committed to such file. It'll always show something.

Comment: We rebooted the server and it all seems to be working now ... hmm...

Comment: How does it solves the OP's problem ? Shouldn't files update to the last commited version of that file ?

Comment: @Amit - We cannot read other people's mind. I didn't solve OPs problem (a reboot did)—I answered his question, that claimed that when "Diff with previous version" shows changes then the file is outdated (that's plain wrong). Had he offered correct and acurate information, a different answer would have been required.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I am also facing similar problem. Never wanted to offend you..